# why new created file in specific branch figures out in master

Tags: git, git-branch

Am new with Git system. In fact, in my local reposiroty I made the folowing actions :

- Create new branch
- move to the new branch
- create a new file "test.txt"
- Switch to master branch

And here I wonder why the file "test.txt" figures out in master branch ?!!

Answer (score 2):

The reason is, you haven't committed the file to either of the branches.

Git can version only those files which are being tracked in the branch.

So what you need to do is

```
cd ~/Desktop/test
mkdir git_repo && cd git_repo
git init
```

With the above, we have created a repo, and now need to add the branches. Git represents branches as pointers to the latest commit in that branch. If you haven't created a commit yet, there's nothing for that branch to point to. So you can't really create branches until you have at least one commit. So lets create a commit.

```
touch testfile1 testfile2
git add testfile1
git commit -m "added testfile1"
```

And now checkout to a new branch and add the other test file in this new branch

```
git checkout -b new
git add testfile2
git commit -m "added testfile2"
```

Note that, testfile1 will also be tracked in this branch, since I had used the `-b` flag.

If now you do an `ls` in this branch and then checkout to the original branch and do an `ls` again, you won't see `testfile2` there.

```
ls
git checkout master
ls
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure you have done all the steps right. The steps to creating the branch is following:

Create the branch on your local machine :

`$ git branch <name_of_your_new_branch>`

Push the branch on github :

`$ git push origin <name_of_your_new_branch>`

Switch to your new branch :

`$ git checkout <name_of_your_new_branch>`

Add your file :

`$ git add <name_of_your_file>`

Commit your file :

`git commit -m "<your_comment_goes_here>"`

Then, you just need to push your `test.txt` to your new branch:

`git push <name_of_your_new_brach>`

**Note that** when you do the `git push`, you must specify a branch. If not, it's normally pushed to your `origin` branch.

If you have done the steps as I mentioned above, you should not see the `test.txt` file in your master branch.

Comment: This question is completely independent of github or any other third party service.

Comment: @Zeta Exactly, It's just the guide `How he should do it in practical work`. You don't need to run the second command to `Push the branch on github`, if you don't want to. However, my answer still describe the main concepts of git.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to add your file to `git` while you were on your new branch. Your actual steps should be

1. Create and switch to new branch
2. Create a new file "test.txt"
3. **Add new file to git**
4. **Commit changes**
5. Switch to master branch

It's important to add the file to git, otherwise it will be ignored if you switch branches, revert changes etc. The following commands result in your desired behaviour. Note that you need to commit something to `master` before you create a new branch.

```
git checkout -b new-branch
echo test > test.txt
git add test.txt
git commit -m "Added a test file"
git checkout master
```